# how to call sql function asp page to fill the column of table

Tags: mysql, asp.net, web

This is my SQL function:

```
create function [dbo].[Book_id](@id int)
returns char(12)
as begin
return 'BK00ID' + right('00000' + covert (varchar(10), @id),5)
end
```

I have created this function because I want when ever I enter others column of table Book_id column will automatically filled.
I also have an identity column(id) which automatically increases.
For example: when the id column is 1 then Book_id column should be BK00ID000001.
Or is there any other way so that this function automatically called without calling from asp page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming SQL Server, you could use a computed column in the table that has the same definition as within your function `'BK00ID' + right('00000' + convert (varchar(10), @id),5)`; this would then automatically be set in the table when the record is saved (though if you were ever to change the ID value then the value of this columns would change with it - if you did not want this, you could make it a default value instead).

Comment: sir i didn't get you here "you could use a computed column in the table that has the same definition as within your function".
whenever i try to insert without calling this function then it shows error.

Comment: When you define your column in the table, instead of specifying a data type specify a calculation that will be used. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250(v=SQL.105).aspx

Comment: sorry for inconvenienced. but sir i saw there is option below as computed column.but i don't know how to give the definition to it.there is two option formula and description . what should write then , please help me

Comment: CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Books](
[ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[BKID]  AS ('BKID00'+right('00000'+CONVERT([varchar](5),[ID]),(5))),
[Title] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Books] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC)
 WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]) ON [PRIMARY]; -- If you try to edit rows in this table, you can only edit the Title column and the BKID column will be set based upon the ID column.